# MySQL, while Loop & comparison with in_array

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM example";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    if (in_array($array['ipsum'], $page1)) {echo "<h2>correct</h2>"; break;} 

    else {echo "<h2>not correct</h2>";} }

    echo "<div id=\"nucleo\"><h3>lorem ipsum</h3><h1>";
    echo $page1;
    echo "</h1>";
```

I have a table with 2 rows in the database: first one is lorem the second one is ipsum (both are INT).
The table is manually compiled when it is needed.
What I want to do is to get the second row (ipsum) and create an array. I don't need to echo values of the array, but I need to compare it with a variable ($page1. this variable is a integer number and it changes continuously).

How could I fix it?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: When $page1 is actually equal to $array['ipusm'] it echos "<h2>not correct</h2>" instead of "<h2>correct</h2>". it seems like there is no comparison at all.

Comment: @chris85 sorry, you are right, they are columns

Comment: Is `$page1` an array or string?

Comment: it is actually a counter. Inside $page1 there is the risult of how many times a button got hit. If that number is equal to one of "ipsum" from the table "example" of the db then it has to echo "correct".

Comment: Okay, I think it is a string in that case. Please try my answer below. This is using the DB to check the value and then if there is a result output "correct".

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you are after. You should look into switching from the `mysql` functions/driver to the `mysqli` or `PDO` drivers.

```
<?php
$page1 = (int)$page1;//force $page1 to be an int to avoid SQL injections
$sql = "SELECT * FROM example where ipsum = " . $page1;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "<h2>correct</h2>"; 
} else {
    echo "<h2>not correct</h2>";} 
}
echo '<div id="nucleo">
        <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
        <h1>' . $page1 . '</h1>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: This is the correct approach with what we know at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `in_array()` to compare two integer values. you should simply use the `===` operator like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM example";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

  if ($array['ipsum'] === $page1) {
    echo "<h2>correct</h2>"; 
    break;
  } else {
    echo "<h2>not correct</h2>";
  } 
}

echo "<div id=\"nucleo\"><h3>lorem ipsum</h3><h1>";
echo $page1;
echo "</h1>";
```

Comment: I know I tried that as well before but it does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're using `===` instead of `==` or adding a cast on either side.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it this way:

```
$array = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    array_push($array, $row["ipsum"]);
} 

if (in_array($page1, $array)) {echo "correct";}
else {echo "not correct"; }
```

I realized by using print_r that the array was not really how I though it was. This way above use all the row of a colums to compose the array... array([0] => row1 [1] => row2 and so on.

Thanks everyone for the help...I apologize for not being very clear about my problem.

Comment: This doesn't take advantage of what a database can provide.

Comment: You should consider my answer below. The way you have solved the problem here may work but it is inefficient. You are likely to have issues in the future if/when your DB gets larger.